# Update Value in same Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I'm trying to update values in the same primary key in which is in 1st row value will apply to the second sequence until the end of the sequence with Primary Key Value.

Here is my sample scenario

[image]

This should be the expected output.

[image]

I don't want also to be updated the rows that are already have values. Is this possible?
I don't have any idea on how to achieve with this output. Can anyone help me? I am using SQL.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by same primary key. Primary key can not be same for 2 rows?

Comment: Sorry for the miss understanding of my example. What I'm trying to say is the primary key for my example is column (ID, SEQUENCE). And must update the value within same ID  range as example above

Comment: Got it. one more question whether you have to pick the value of sequence `1` always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions and an updatable CTE.

If there is only one non-`null` value per `id`, then a window min or max is sufficient:

```
with cte as (
    select value, min(value) over(partition by id) as new_value
    from mytable t
)
update cte set value = new_value where value is null
```

If you specifically want the row where `sequence` has value `1`, use conditional window aggregation:

```
with cte as (
    select value, 
        min(case when sequence = 1 then value end) over(partition by id) as new_value
    from mytable t
)
update cte set value = new_value where value is null
```

Finally, if you want the row with the minimum `sequence`, regardless of the its actual value:

```
with cte as (
    select value, 
        first_value(value) over(partition by id order by sequence) as new_value
    from mytable t
)
update cte set value = new_value where value is null
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @GMB but sorry for late notice.. I'm updating my question though. problem is I don't want existing values to be updated

Comment: @davinceleecode: this does not update existing values - condition `where value is null` in the outer query guarantees that only `null` values are updated.

Answer (score 0):

The DENSE_RANK windowed function is handy for this type of sequence.  If the goal is to just return the value, there is no need to store it as it can be obtained directly in the select.

```
DECLARE @Test as Table (
    Id char(1),
    Seq int,
    Val varchar(10)
)

INSERT @Test (Id, Seq)
VALUES
    ('A','1'),
    ('A','2'),
    ('A','3'),
    ('A','4'),
    ('A','5'),
    ('B','1'),
    ('B','2'),
    ('B','3'),
    ('B','4'),
    ('C','4'),
    ('C','5');

-- Select Only

SELECT Id, Seq, 
    'Test' + LTRIM(STR(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id))) as [Val]
FROM @Test

-- Update via derived table

UPDATE t
SET Val = 'Test' + LTRIM(STR(Seq2))
FROM @Test t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Id, Seq, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id) as [Seq2]
    FROM @Test
) v
ON v.Id = t.Id AND v.Seq = t.Seq
```